# Filter by schema in a Browser popup

Tags: gui-extensions

I'm trying to make a GUI extension that opens a popup when you are in an RTF field.

The popup contains a browser button to select some components.

How to filter the type of components to select in the browser by a specific schema?

The idea is to add a button to the ribbon of text area. That should work like the standard hyperlink button of tridion, with a browser button to insert tcm:link in the rich text body.
The requirement is that the components wich could be selected must be of one specific schema.

something like:

```
...
case "tcm:":
        if (p.NewLink.href.indexOf("tcm:") != "-1")
        {
            var item = $models.getItem(p.NewLink.href);
            if (item)
            {
                p.NewLink.tcmname = item.getStaticTitle();
            }
        }

        c.BtnBrowse.enable();
        c.BtnOpenURL.disable();
        c.FieldUrl.disabled = true;
        c.FieldUrl.value = p.NewLink.value;

        this._setUrl(c.FieldUrl.value);

        c.RowUrl.style.display = "";
        c.RowAnchor.style.display = "none";
        p.NewLink.tcmuri = p.NewLink.href;
```

Comment: Please give some more details about your requirements. not clear from your question

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assuming, you`re opening item select dialog (Tridion.Cme.Views.ItemSelectDialog) to select the component you are interested in, you need to specify a filter in dialog features.

As an example when you click on browse button to open popup dialog:

```
Extension.Browse.prototype.onOpenClik = function Extension$browse(isControlVisible)
{
    var contextItemID = this.getContextUri();

    var dialogPopup = $popupManager.createExternalContentPopup(
        $cme.Popups.ITEM_SELECT.URL.format(contextItemID, ""),
        $cme.Popups.ITEM_SELECT.FEATURES,
        {
            filter: this.getFilter()
        });
    dialogPopup.open();
};
```

Where filter is `Tridion.ContentManager.ListFilter` with all associated properties, such as 
`(new Tridion.ContentManager.ListFilter()).conditions.BasedOnSchema` 
where you can specify the schemas you have to deal with.